# Python Importing Problem No Module Named X

Tags: python, flask, import, module, package

I am new to Python and I have been trying to solve this import problem, but I cannot seem to find a solution from ChatGPT or on the net. See my project's structure in the picture.

Here is my views.py:

```
from algorithms.CPU_Processes import Process
from algorithms.FCFS import FCFS
from algorithms.SJF import SJF
from algorithms.PriorityNP import PriorityNP
from algorithms.PriorityP import PriorityP
from algorithms.RoundRobin import RoundRobin
from algorithms.SRTF import SRTF
from algorithms.MLQ import MLQ
from algorithms.MLFQ import MLFQ
```

and here is my FCFS.py:

```
from CPU_Processes import Process
```

I am receiving this error when I try to run views.py:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\pc user\Desktop\3104\CPU-Scheduling\Calculator\views.py", line 4, in 
from algorithms.FCFS import FCFS
File "c:\Users\pc user\Desktop\3104\CPU-Scheduling\Calculator\algorithms\FCFS.py", line 1, in 
from CPU_Processes import Process
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CPU_Processes'

It says that it cannot find the CPU_Process module, but I can run FCFS.py just fine even though it requires the module, and I can also run the rest of the files in the algorithms directory that require the said module. However, when I try to run views.py, which is outside of the algorithms folder, it generates the no module named error. I have tried using absolute imports like `from Calculator.algorithms.CPU_Processes import Process` in views.py, but it just tells me it cannot find the Calculator module even though it is clearly there. I also tried using `from algorithms.CPU_Processes import Process` in FCFS.py, but it does not run anymore if I use absolute import because it just says "no module named algorithms" even though it is clearly there. Oddly enough, I can run FCFS.py in Pycharm whether the import is `from algorithms.CPU_Processes import Process` or `from CPU_Processes import Process`. I tried using the same Python interpreter Pycharm uses in VSCode, but still no luck.

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SMBc.png)

I have tried adding these lines:

```
import sys
import os

# Add the top-level directory to the Python path
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

to the beginning of my views.py, but still no luck. I have also tried running `python views.py` directly in the command prompt in the Calculator directory, but still no luck. I also tried entering this in cmd: set PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\pc user\Desktop\3104\CPU-Scheduling\Calculator;%PYTHONPATH%, which is basically the path to my project, but still no luck.

If I use `from algorithms.CPU_Processes import Process` in FCFS.py, I cannot run the file anymore but I can run views.py. But when I try to send data from javascript to views.py, I just get an internal server error.

To sum it up:

1. I can run FCFS.py using `from CPU_Processes import Process` in FCFS.py, but if I do that, I am unable to run views.py because it suggests CPU_Processes module cannot be found.
2. I cannot run FCFS.py using `from algorithms.CPU_Processes import Process` because it says no module named algorithms, but I can run views.py and app.py with it, only for it to say internal server error when views.py receives data from client.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make it

```
from .CPU_Processes import Process
```

in the `FCFS.py` file

Comment: Did this help you fix the issue?